# Why does my bootstrap 4 menu items not take up full width in my vertical menu?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with a menu im trying to create. I kinda got the old bootstrap, but this whole flex-thingy is confusing for me. So, i want to have a 80px dark vertical side menu and the rest of the screen should be a "working area". My problem is that the items in the side menu does not have full width (see the borders below) and I cant seem to figure out why not. I am guessing right now, that it has something to do with the flexbox - an item taking up only the space it needs. Im have copied the code from bootstrap 4 website and modified a bit. But that last bit, where I can get full width on the items - that one I am missing.

```css
.nav-item{
color:#FEFEFE!important;
border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Ticket</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%">
    <div class="row" style="height:100%">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xl-1" style="padding:0px!important;height:100%">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm px-0 flex-row " style="background-color:#333;height:100%;">
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarWEX">
            <div class="nav flex-column">
              <a routerLink="/" class="nav-item">Home</a>
              <a routerLink="/first" class="nav-item">First Item</a>
              <a routerLink="/second" class="nav-item">Second Item</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col py-2">

        <h2>Hello There</h2>
        <p>Test test test test test test test</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To clarify, you want your menu to take up the full width of the viewport on a mobile device? So that your main content is pushed down, below the menu? Or do you simply want each of the navigation links to span the full width of the black menu container?

Comment: Use `w-100` on the nav.... `class="nav w-100 flex-column"`

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to your `.nav-item`, it's because `.nav` doesn't take full width of its parent. Try updating bootstrap to 4.1 and insert `.flex-fill` to your `nav`:

```css
.nav-item{
color:#FEFEFE!important;
border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Ticket</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%">
    <div class="row" style="height:100%">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xl-1" style="padding:0px!important;height:100%">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm px-0 flex-row " style="background-color:#333;height:100%;">
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarWEX">
            <div class="nav flex-column flex-fill">
              <a routerLink="/" class="nav-item">Home</a>
              <a routerLink="/first" class="nav-item">First Item</a>
              <a routerLink="/second" class="nav-item">Second Item</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col py-2">

        <h2>Hello There</h2>
        <p>Test test test test test test test</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

In case you don't want to update bootstrap, you can simply add `flex: 1 1 auto` to `.nav` style:

```css
.nav-item{
color:#FEFEFE!important;
border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Ticket</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%">
    <div class="row" style="height:100%">
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 col-xl-1" style="padding:0px!important;height:100%">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm px-0 flex-row " style="background-color:#333;height:100%;">
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarWEX">
            <div class="nav flex-column" style="flex: 1 1 auto">
              <a routerLink="/" class="nav-item">Home</a>
              <a routerLink="/first" class="nav-item">First Item</a>
              <a routerLink="/second" class="nav-item">Second Item</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col py-2">

        <h2>Hello There</h2>
        <p>Test test test test test test test</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```